# Error al subir proyecto a un repositorio Git Hub con Git Bash

Tags: cmd, git-bash

instale el Git BASH y a través de la consola cmd de windows 7 utilize los comandos cd "path de mi proyecto local", despues ingrese el comando git init, despues el git add . Y por ultimo git commit -m "mi primer commit" pero la consola me muestra el siguiente mensaje. 
no se como solucionarlo para poder subir mi proyecto al repositorio de git hub.

Warning: Your console probably doesn't support Unicode. if your experience. If you experience strange characters in the output, considerer switching to a TrueType font such as
Consolas

Answer (score 1):

Cambia la fuente de tu CMD, click derecho en el marco de la ventana, propiedades, fuente y ahí le pones `Consolas` por ejemplo.

[image: Solucion Git Bash Unicode Warning]